# The upgraded apk's package name must be the same as the one it is replacing in android google play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I need a help in publishing new application in google play.
 I had a previous application that was published yesterday. But I saw an error in there cause my *apview is blank.*

I suspect that I use the `debug.keystore` when I published my app instead of creating my private key which will use to get the `md5 cert` and not from `debug.keystore`. But in google play it says that you can't delete your previous published application.

So what I did was to publish a new one and deactivate the previously published app. But there was an error publishing a new app. it says *The upgraded apk's package name(com.myproject.final) must be the same as the one it is replacing(com.myproject2.finale2)* , google play says in their developer apps that *If the package name and signing certificate do not match those of the existing version, Google Play will consider it a new application, publish it as such, and will not offer it to existing users as an update.*

Google play refers it as an update to my previous app, but thats not what I want. I want to publish a new application.  What should I do?
 Is there a way on how to resolve this problem rather creating a new google play account? 
Paying 25 dollars again is too much for me.

And another thing is how many application can a user upload in one google play account?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the package name in android manifest it is actually a new application. So the existing users who have installed your app will not get an update in their phone, but they can see the new application in Play Store and download it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. But google play refer my project as an update of the previous system.. even though my package name in manifest is different from the previous one.. and i use my private key not the debug.keystore that i used.. how come that google play didnt recognizes my app as a new one and not an update of the previous one?? please help T_T

Answer (score 0):

We can upload any number of application within single account having different package names.